# Should I save this in the same user collection or create another collection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, graph

I am creating this project with reactjs and firebase firestore where users can register and log in to this website. The user has a QR code to be scanned by the admin and retrieves information

I'm not sure if I should create another collection when the admin submits the entered vaccination status of the user or should I just still save it in the users collection.

I'm asking this because I will be creating a monthly graph for each of the vaccines for those who were at least at 1 dose or fully vaccinated. Will this be fine if I'll just save it in the firestore by creating another collection or just save it in the users collections?

Comment: What do the sessions looks like and how many sessions can a single user have ?

Comment: The session that I meant was the vaccine session of the user. I created 1 form for the admin to update the vaccination information of the user

Comment: So if each user can have only 2 doses you can just store the details in a map in same user's doc? `{..restFields, doses: {first: {...}, second: {...}}}`

Comment: so then I could just save it in the same users collection, right? It won't cause a problem with the graph? I'll just have to user `where()` or something else?

Comment: Can you specify what kind of query you'll require? Can you write it here? To use where queries on nested object you can use dot notation. `.where("doses.first.type", "==", "AstraZeneca")`

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but I will have to create a graph similar to the one above for each type of vaccine. And also I will have to create a graph for the side effects per dosage of each type of the vaccines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each user can have at most 2 doses, you can simply store the data as a map in user's document.

```js
{
  firstName: "name",
  ...otherFields,
  doses: {
    1: {
      ...dose1Info
    },
    2: {
      ...dose2Info
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use `dot notation` to query using those nested field like this:

```js
const query = colRef.where("doses.1.type", "==", "AstraZeneca")
```

This query will return documents of users whose first does was AstraZeneca. Similarly you can query based on other dose info fields.

Comment: One question though, what date format should I save for each doses of the vaccine since I would also be making a graph per month?

Comment: @AranyaDream you can use Firestore timestamp or just a timestamp `Date.now()`. Both of them should work equally fine.

Comment: oh okay. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While @Dharmaraj answer will work, you can also consider an alternative solution that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- vaccinType: "AstraZeneca"
            |
            --- doseOne: true
            |
            --- doseTwo: true
```

To find all users that are vaccinated with "AstraZeneca", you can use the following query:

```
const query = usersRef.where("vaccinType", "==", "AstraZeneca")
```

To find all users that are vaccinated with "AstraZeneca" and got the first dose simply use:

```
const query = usersRef.where("vaccinType", "==", "AstraZeneca")
                  .where("doseOne", "==", true)
```

To find all users that are vaccinated with "AstraZeneca" and got the first and the second dose you can use:

```
const query = usersRef.where("vaccinType", "==", "AstraZeneca")
                  .where("doseOne", "==", true)
                  .where("doseTwo", "==", true)
```

If you need additional data the doses, you can create two separate fields for that.

Comment: Thank you. I just want to ask for clarifications, the vaccine information entered by the admin in the form will be stored in another collection and this collection is the `$uid (document)` under the users collection you posted above?

Comment: If the vaccine information that is entered by the admin corresponds only to a single user, then yes, you should store that information under the user object (the same document). In this way, you can read only a single document to get the right information.

Comment: yes, the admin will only edit the information per user. The admin has to scan the QR code of the user and from there the admin will be able to enter the vaccine information

Comment: The best solution is to save that information in the User document.

Comment: One question though, what date format should I save for each doses of the vaccine since I would also be making a graph per month?

Comment: You should then consider using a timestamp.

Comment: oh okay. Thank you